# Formation of Binary Heaps using Arrays Shortcut

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, heap, binary-heap

If we arrange array in ascending order, then we'll get Binary Heap. Is there any drawback of this advantage. If yes then what will be the reason of that?

Comment: The drawback is that sorting the array will take longer than using the traditional BuildHeap method.

Answer (score 0):

"Arranging array in ascending order, then we'll get Binary Heap". This is correct.
Now it depends upon which algorithm you use to sort the array in ascending order. Best Sorting Algorithm perform with complexity `O(NLogN)`.

While the algorithm `Build_Heap` to just create a binary heap has complexity of `O(N)`.

Unless and until you use non-comparison based sorting method like `Counting Sort` your complexity for creating binary heap will be atleast `O(NLogN)` and atmost `O(N^2)`.

So traditional method of creating binary heap is favorable.

Although `Counting Sort` will take `O(N)` time but it will require extra space `O(N)`, while traditional `Build_Heap` will be create binary heap **in-place**.

Comment: You cannot do a comparison sort in O(N) time. Comparison sorting is O(N log N). Non-comparison methods (like radix sort) are potentially O(N), but require extra space.

Comment: @JimMischel: By-mistake wrote `Comparison` instead of `Counting`. Thanks for the correction.